# What impact do indexes have on the performance of table modifications?

Tags: sql-server, index

I have always wondered what the effect indexes have on table modification in SQL Server. Will modification of a table will be slower with an increased number of indexes applied to that table?

My gut feeling says that this will induce overhead of re-indexing but I could be wrong.

Comment: @gbn I don't know...that question assumes that performance is degraded, this one is asking how it's degraded. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "table modification"? `ALTER TABLE` or CRUD without the "R"?

Answer (score 5):

As @mrdenny said, every index will need to be changed with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations.

If you are weary about an index is actually be utilized to its fully capacity, and that it's not just a performance degrade, you should query the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`.

Here are some important fields that are returned:

- **user_seeks**
  *bigint*
  Number of seeks by user queries.
- **user_scans**
  *bigint*
  Number of scans by user queries.
- **user_lookups**
  *bigint*
  Number of bookmark lookups by user queries.
- **user_updates**
  *bigint*
  Number of updates by user queries.
- **last_user_seek**
  *datetime*
  Time of last user seek
- **last_user_scan**
  *datetime*
  Time of last user scan.
- **last_user_lookup**
  *datetime*
  Time of last user lookup.
- **last_user_update**
  *datetime*
  Time of last user update.

Comment: +1 for the DMV suggestion. This will work on versions 2005 and above.

Answer (score 4):

Every index that you add to a table will slow down insert/update/delete operations as there are now more physical changes which need to be made when the insert/update/delete operations happen.

Comment: Adding to @mrdenny's good answer...if you're worried about performance degradation, capture a sample database workload using Profiler. Replay this workload against a test database with/without indexes and compare performance metrics. This will tell you if the benefits of the index exceed the cost of maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the general answer - yes, it will degrade CUD operations performance with the possible benefit of select-queries

Worst case - bulk updates - this involving internal sort-spool operations which VERY painful for server

Answer (score 0):

In the case of updates, I believe the updated column(s) would need to be involved in the Indexes before the Update would be slowed by indexes.  I don't have direct testing on this theory, but it makes sense to me.